# Duplicates in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that I want remove/supress duplicate values from.

I'm working with 3 tables

Table 1: AWARD

| AWARD_ID | IDENTIFIER | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 200112 | 3000 |
| 1002 | 200113 | 4000 |
| 1003 | 200114 | 5000 |

Table 2:INSTALMENT_PAYMENT

| INSTALMENT_ID | AWARD_ID | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 4000 |
| 2 | 1001 | -1000 |
| 3 | 1002 | 4000 |
| 4 | 1003 | 1000 |
| 5 | 1003 | 1000 |
| 6 | 1003 | 3000 |

Table 3:RECON

| ID | REFERENCE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200112 | 3000 |
| 2 | 200113 | 4000 |
| 3 | 200114 | 5000 |

So if I join TABLES 1 AND 2 For a simple query

`SELECT A.AWARD_ID, A.IDENTIFIER IP.AMOUNT,
FROM AWARD A, INSTALMENT_PAYMENTS IP
WHERE A.AWARD_ID=IP.AWARD_ID'

I get a return that looks like:

| AWARD_ID | IDENTIFIER | INSTALMENT_ID | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 200112 | 1 | 4000 |
| 1001 | 200112 | 2 | -1000 |
| 1002 | 200113 | 3 | 4000 |
| 1003 | 200114 | 4 | 1000 |
| 1003 | 200114 | 5 | 1000 |
| 1003 | 200114 | 6 | 3000 |

If I add table 3 to the mix (for augments sake this data is supplied from 3rd party for reconciliation purposes and cannot be broken down to transaction level as in table 2)

`SELECT A.AWARD_ID, A.IDENTIFIER IP.AMOUNT R.AMOUNT AS RECON_AMOUNT,  FROM AWARD A, INSTALMENT_PAYMENTS IP, RECON R WHERE A.AWARD_ID=IP.AWARD_ID' AND A.IDENTIFER= R.REFERENCE`

I get a return that looks like:

| AWARD_ID | IDENTIFIER | INSTALMENT_ID | AMOUNT | RECON_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 200112 | 1 | 4000 | 3000 |
| 1001 | 200112 | 2 | -1000 | 3000 |
| 1002 | 200113 | 3 | 4000 | 4000 |
| 1003 | 200114 | 4 | 1000 | 5000 |
| 1003 | 200114 | 5 | 1000 | 5000 |
| 1003 | 200114 | 6 | 3000 | 5000 |

What I'm looking to do is suppress the identical values/duplicates in columns AWARD_ID, IDENTIFIER AND RECON_AMOUNT - if possible to look like:

| AWARD_ID | IDENTIFIER | INSTALMENT_ID | AMOUNT | RECON_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 200112 | 1 | 4000 | 3000 |
|  |  | 2 | -1000 |  |
| 1002 | 200113 | 3 | 4000 | 4000 |
| 1003 | 200114 | 4 | 1000 | 5000 |
|  |  | 5 | 1000 |  |
|  |  | 6 | 3000 |  |

Comment: you are going to need to use an analytic function like row_number() with some CASE logic to do that.

Comment: While this is possible in SQL, better deal with display issues in your GUI layer, i.e. your app or Website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE WHEN row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY award_id ORDER BY instalment_id ) = 1 THEN award_id ELSE null END award_id`..  And similar variations for the other columns.

I don't have your data model, but here is a working example of the concept using `DBA_OBJECTS`.

```
select CASE WHEN row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY owner, object_type ORDER BY object_name, last_ddl_time) = 1 THEN owner ELSE NULL END owner, 
       CASE WHEN row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY owner, object_type ORDER BY object_name, last_ddl_time) = 1 THEN object_type ELSE NULL END object_type,
       object_name, 
       last_ddl_time
from dba_objects o
order by o.owner, o.object_type, o.object_name, o.last_ddl_time;
```

> ```
> +-------+-------------+--------------------------+---------------+
> | OWNER | OBJECT_TYPE |       OBJECT_NAME        | LAST_DDL_TIME |
> +-------+-------------+--------------------------+---------------+
> | ABM   | INDEX       | ABM_CURRS_PK             | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_MDLS_PK              | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_MLS_ACTS_N1          | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_MLS_DS_PK            | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_MLS_PK               | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_MLS_RESOURCES_PK     | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_MLS_RES_PK           | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_MLS_RE_DS_PK         | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_RES_PK               | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_TAGS_PK              | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_TAG_SETS_PK          | 12-DEC-21     |
> | ABM   | TABLE       | ABM_CURRS                | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_MDLS                 | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_MLS                  | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_MLS_ACTS             | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_MLS_DS               | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_MLS_RES              | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_MLS_RESOURCES        | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_MLS_RE_DS            | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_RES                  | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_TAGS                 | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | ABM_TAG_SETS             | 12-DEC-21     |
> | ADDS  | INDEX       | SAS_ARIA_FEED_AUDIT_N1   | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | SAS_ARIA_FEED_AUDIT_U1   | 12-DEC-21     |
> |       |             | SAS_ARIA_FEED_STAGING_N1 | 12-DEC-21     |
> +-------+-------------+--------------------------+---------------+
> ```

Make sure you `ORDER BY` your main query the same way that you `ORDER BY` in the `row_number()` window clause.  Also, make sure to `ORDER BY` using the table alias in your main query (e.g., `ORDER BY a.award_id` instead of just `ORDER BY award_id`)

Comment: Perfect, I was so close to it but my syntax was a bit out.  Your example was very easy to follow.  Thanks Matthew.